# Parametric vs non parametric tests for Likert items?

Tags: anova, normality-assumption, likert, kruskal-wallis-test

I have conducted a survey and am now trying to figure out how to analyse the results. I have a series of 6-point Likert items, which I have coded like this:

-3 Strongly disagree

-2 Disagree

-1 Somewhat disagree

1 Somewhat agree

2 Agree

3 Strongly agree

/ No opinion/refuse to answer (counted as missing values)

My questions are:

1) Is it an acceptable way of coding the answers, given the absence of a neutral point 0?

2) I would like to compare the results among several independent group samples. Should I use parametric tests (ANOVA, independent t test) or non-parametric tests (Kruskal Wallis, Mann Whitney)? My data is often not normally distributed, and my sample sizes (2, 3 and 4 samples) are all larger then 15 but vary in size (between 17 and 100). I have read that the parametric tests are robust against the violation of normality but am not sure which would be the best option.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check what people in your field use. Most published papers in my area of interest would use anova.

Comment: Thank you. Some use anovas and others use Chi-square tests... I would go for anovas as well but was concerned about the absence of the 0 value and its potential effect on the results, and can't find anything on this topic

Comment: Absence of zero is irrelevant.

Comment: So, just to make sure, coding the answers from -3 to 3 (with no 0) or from 1 to 6 would yield similar means and results?

Comment: Different means, same difference in means, standard errors, p values, etc. (Sorry for being terse, ok my phone on a train.)

Comment: Actually, 1 to 6 is not generally going to give the same difference in means nor standard errors nor p-values, because -3 to 3 with no central 0 has a different distribution than 1 to 6 (it has a gap in the center which 1-6 doesn't). They'll often be fairly close though

Comment: Sorry, I had not seen that! Thank you for your answers. In that case would you advise me to keep the -3 to 3 distribution or would it be better if I used the 1 to 6 distribution?